# How to reference methods from within the same class in f#?

Tags: oop, f#

I have been programming in f# for a few weeks now and decided that I would now try out some of the object oriented features. I am wondering though, how to reference a method in a class from within another method in that class. Here is an (admittedly contrived) but deliberately simple example of what I am talking about.

```
type MathsOperations =
    static member addOne (a : int) : int =
        a + 1

    static member addTwo (a : int) : int =
        1 + (addOne a)
```

Here in the `addTwo` method I get the error that `addOne` is not defined.

Comment: `1 + MathsOperations.addOne a`

Comment: Thank you. I figured it would be something obvious like that but finding the syntax for object oriented stuff in a functional first language is remarkable difficult.

Comment: That's what the documentation is for.

Comment: That said, in real-world F# code, that should probably not be a `type` with static methods, but rather a `module` with functions, which is the idiomatic equivalent to a static class.

Comment: @TeaDrivenDev The only issue is overloading the operators without overwriting their definition for primitive types.